# Corona widget.newButton change defaultFile

Tags: widget, coronasdk

Considering I am defining some button like the following:

```
-- title button
titleButton = widget.newButton{
    label="",
    width=265, height=70,
    defaultFile = "images/title.png",
    overFile = "images/title_clicked.png",
    onEvent = handlePlayEvent
}
titleButton:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
titleButton.x = display.contentWidth / 2
titleButton.y = display.contentHeight / 4
```

Is it possible to modify the button's defaultFile and overFile after creation from some other function.

I have searched the docs and couldn't find anything. Any tip would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change **defaultFile** and **overFile** after its creation.

Like `display.newImage()`, you can't directly change the image itself unless it is an image sheet.

But you can use [image sheet](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/graphics/newImageSheet.html) as a button. You can change its frame whenever you want.

Comment: How would you do this?